# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{(2+x^2)^n}$ converges uniformly for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: uniform-convergence

Given the sum
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{(2+x^2)^n}
$$
I have to show that $S$ converges uniformly for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I know that I probably have to use Weisterstrass' M-test to find a sequence of positive numbers ${M_n}$ satisfying that 
$
|f_n(x)| \leq M_n$ and that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n < \infty$ but I am not sure whether my solution is correct. Do you mind verifying?

As $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we must have that
$$
\frac{1}{(2+x^2)^n} \leq \frac{1}{n}
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This means that 
$$
\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{(2+x^2)^n} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
and from analysis we know that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
converges. Thus Weiterstrass' M-test gives that S converges uniformly. Is this approach ok?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to note that, since $(2+x^2)\ge 2$, we have $\frac{1}{n(2+x^2)^n}\le\frac{1}{2^n}$?

Comment: Yes I see that which is a geometric series which converges for |t| = |1/2| < 1. But I am not sure whether my attempt was ok still?

Comment: I am not sure whether or not I am miscalculating anything but I can't see for $n=1$ and $x=0$ that $$ \frac{1}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{(2+0^2)^1} = \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{1}{1^2} = 1 $$ shouldn't be true?

Comment: no no, you are right, I miscalculated. Then yes, your approach is ok. Although I find it harder than the simple bound $2^{-n}$.

Comment: Thanks man! I will keep your approach in mind as well for similar exercises :)